# StringBuffer Hangman Game Null Exception Error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm making a simple game where 1 player chooses the word and the other player must guess the word in an any amount of tries.

```
public class JavaHang
```

{

```
//Data Members
private String secretWord;
private StringBuffer blankGuess;

//Constructor
public JavaHang(String s)
{
    secretWord = s;
    StringBuffer blankGuess = new StringBuffer( secretWord );
}
public void setBlankGuess()
{
    for(int i = 0;i<secretWord.length();i++)
    {
        blankGuess.setCharAt(i, '_');
    }
}
```

I have a lot more than this but I believe there is the location of my error. I am getting a  NullPointerException. How does the value of "Stringbuffer blankGuess" have a null value?

Comment: Where does it say the error is happening? Can you copy in the stack trace?

Comment: Please post stacktrace and also point out the line in which the NPE occurs.

Comment: The error is in the line "blankGuess.setCharAt(i, '_');"

Answer (score 4):

You're getting an NPE becaue you've declared `blankGuess` a second time inside the method therefore you're shadowing/hiding the one you think you're using (the one declared as a field in the class).

Change:

```
StringBuffer blankGuess = new StringBuffer( secretWord );
```

to:

```
blankGuess = new StringBuffer( secretWord );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public JavaHang(String s)
{
    secretWord = s;
    StringBuffer blankGuess = new StringBuffer( secretWord );
}
```

`blankGuess` is a local varaible declaredand initialized in the constructor, I am pretty sure that you are using the instance variable which isn't initialized and calling **string buffers method** leads to `NullpointerException`. You have to just initialize the instance variable `blankGuess` like below.

```
 public JavaHang(String s)
    {
        secretWord = s;
         blankGuess = new StringBuffer( secretWord );
    }
```

Comment: Nice call. Without even seeing the code.

Comment: Another newbie mistake (; thanks for the help!